# CSS style issue in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, select

I have this example:

http://musicexploration.net/test-page

How I can make the first select field to look like in Chrome? ( Without the right arrow and select instrument text in the middle )

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery select option to customize your select field. It will be all browser compatible.

Comment: I don't know how. Because I use an plugin for this. It's an Joomla component. SobiPro. An that it's an extend search plugin. Without jQuery I can't make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even without jQuery but that will be very difficult and time consuming. 

Using a already developed [Free jQuery Select Option Builder](http://www.scenebit.com/blog/5-most-popular-jquery-select-menu-plugins/) is faster and easier.